# Wordpress Custom Post Type Handling, Next, Previous

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

So, I have a custom post type 'success case'.
the posts are classified by categories. Thing is, right now the client has only 3 success case posts, divided into 3 categories. What I want is to create next/previous buttons that link to the next/previous posts, arranged by date.
the normal `next_post_link();` or `previous_post_link();` functions aren't working unless the posts has the same category, which they don't.
I looked it up a bit and couldn't find the answer here or anywhere else.
Here's a [link to one post](http://91.202.168.37/~ibi/success_case/gauzy-local-glass-processors/) if you want to be more connected :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck once for pagination links for custom post. Hope you will find the following code helpful that I used then:

```
        $pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
    $pagenum = intval($pagenum);

    $page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '', 
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo; Previous', 'text-domain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next &raquo;', 'text-domain' ),
    'total' => 1,
    'current' => $pagenum
            ) );

    if ( $page_links ) 
        {
            echo '<ul class="pagination"><li class="page-item" style="margin: 1em 0">' . $page_links . '</li></ul>';
        }
```